# Where is linux kernel source starting point?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Well, after finishing an advanced C programming course i decided to take a look at the code of Giants. I wanted to have a look at Linux kernel source but as much as it's complicated I can't get to the starting point ! The main function or the first line of code to be executed after grub loads.

Would you please help me locate the first line of code to be executed in linux kernel 2.6 ?

Comment: I would recommend starting with something simpler than a kernel.

Comment: Yes, or at least something simpler than a monolithic kernel.  Perhaps start with [Fiasco](http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/fiasco/)?

Comment: Open version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266063/does-kernel-have-main-function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`linux/init/main.c:start_kernel()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.36/init/main.c#L536)

Comment: That's not even close to the start, despite the name :)

Comment: But it's a good starting point :)