# Does Linux kernel have main function?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning `Device Driver` and `Kernel` programming.According to Jonathan Corbet book we do not have `main()` function in device drivers.

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int my_init(void)
{
     return  0;
}

static void my_exit(void)
{
     return;
}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
```

Here I have two questions :

1. Why we do not need `main()` function in Device Drivers?
2. Does Kernel have `main()` function?

Comment: If no one knows the answer why you down vote my question?

Comment: With `main()` you propably mean what `main()` is to a program, namely its "entry point"?

Comment: @alk..Book says that we have `init_module` as entry point and `exit_module` as exit point. I am coming from `C` background, and learn that none program can execute without `main()` function. so just want to know how drivers working without `main()`.

Comment: This should also be written in the book.

Comment: @alk... No it is not written there. That`s why i am asking this.

Comment: Does the book really word this: "*`exit_module()` as exit point*"? Which book is this?

Comment: @alk.. Book name is `Linux Device Driver` by Jonathan Corbet.

Comment: Also asked by the same user here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86955/10454

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fundamentally, there is nothing special about a routine being named `main()`.  As alluded to above, `main()` serves as the entry point for an executable load module.  However, you can define different entry points for a load module.  In fact, you can define more than one entry point, for example, refer to your favorite dll.

From the operating system's (OS) point of view, all it really needs is the address of the entry point of the code that will function as a device driver.  The OS will pass control to that entry point when the device driver is required to perform I/O to the device.

A system programmer defines (each OS has its own method) the connection between a device, a load module that functions as the device's driver, and the name of the entry point in the load module.

Each OS has its own kernel (obviously) and some might/maybe start with `main()` but I would be surprised to find a kernel that used `main()` other than in a simple one, such as UNIX!  By the time you are writing kernel code you have long moved past the requirement to name every module you write as `main()`.

Hope this helps?

Found this code snippet from the kernel for Unix Version 6.  As you can see `main()` is just another program, trying to get started!

```
main()
{
     extern schar;
     register i, *p;
     /*
     * zero and free all of core
     */

     updlock = 0;
     i = *ka6 + USIZE;
     UISD->r[0] = 077406;
     for(;;) {
        if(fuibyte(0) < 0) break;
        clearsig(i);
        maxmem++;
        mfree(coremap, 1, i);
         i++;
     }
     if(cputype == 70) 
     for(i=0; i<62; i=+2) {
       UBMAP->r[i] = i<<12;
       UBMAP->r[i+1] = 0;
      }

    // etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: JackCColeman... So Kernel code can have main().if you can provide some snippet of such code, it would be a great help.

Comment: @Krishna, no I did **NOT** mean to imply this.  Rather, when writing a kernel a programmer is experienced enough to know how to define the entry point of a module in the code and to the linkage editor, and is **NOT** bound by using the `main()` convention used in application (i.e. non-kernel code).

Comment: @Krishna, well, I can just eat my words!  Found a book on Unix Version 6 that lists the source to Unix (the "Lions" book) and it lists a module named `main()` that initializes Unix control blocks.  But, like I said naming a module `main()` does NOT give it any special status.

Comment: @Krishna, why did you uncheck my answer?

Answer (score 19):

**`start_kernel`**

On 4.2, [`start_kernel` from `init/main.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.2/init/main.c#L497) is a considerable initialization process and could be compared to a `main` function.

It is the first arch independent code to run, and sets up a large part of the kernel. So much like `main`, `start_kernel` is preceded by some lower level setup code (done in the `crt*` objects in userland `main`), after which the "main" generic C code runs.

**How `start_kernel` gets called in x86_64**

`arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S`, a linker script, sets:

```
ENTRY(phys_startup_64)
```

and

```
phys_startup_64 = startup_64 - LOAD_OFFSET;
```

and:

```
#define LOAD_OFFSET __START_KERNEL_map
```

`arch/x86/include/asm/page_64_types.h` defines `__START_KERNEL_map` as:

```
#define __START_KERNEL_map  _AC(0xffffffff80000000, UL)
```

which is the kernel entry address. TODO how is that address reached exactly? I have to understand the interface Linux exposes to bootloaders.

`arch/x86/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S` sets the very first bootloader section as:

```
.text :  AT(ADDR(.text) - LOAD_OFFSET) {
    _text = .;
    /* bootstrapping code */
    HEAD_TEXT
```

`include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h` defines `HEAD_TEXT`:

```
#define HEAD_TEXT  *(.head.text)
```

`arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S` defines `startup_64`. That is the very first x86 kernel code that runs. It does a *lot* of low level setup, including segmentation and paging.

That is then the first thing that runs because the file starts with:

```
.text
__HEAD
.code64
.globl startup_64
```

and `include/linux/init.h` defines `__HEAD` as:

```
#define __HEAD      .section    ".head.text","ax"
```

so the same as the very first thing of the linker script.

At the end it calls `x86_64_start_kernel` a bit awkwardly with and `lretq`:

```
movq    initial_code(%rip),%rax
pushq   $0      # fake return address to stop unwinder
pushq   $__KERNEL_CS    # set correct cs
pushq   %rax        # target address in negative space
lretq
```

and:

```
.balign 8
GLOBAL(initial_code)
.quad   x86_64_start_kernel
```

`arch/x86/kernel/head64.c` defines `x86_64_start_kernel` which calls `x86_64_start_reservations` which calls `start_kernel`.

**arm64 entry point**

The very first arm64 that runs on an v5.7 uncompressed kernel is defined at https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/v5.7/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S#L72 so either the `add x13, x18, #0x16` or `b  stext` depending on `CONFIG_EFI`:

```
    __HEAD
_head:
    /*
     * DO NOT MODIFY. Image header expected by Linux boot-loaders.
     */
#ifdef CONFIG_EFI
    /*
     * This add instruction has no meaningful effect except that
     * its opcode forms the magic "MZ" signature required by UEFI.
     */
    add x13, x18, #0x16
    b   stext
#else
    b   stext               // branch to kernel start, magic
    .long   0               // reserved
#endif
    le64sym _kernel_offset_le       // Image load offset from start of RAM, little-endian
    le64sym _kernel_size_le         // Effective size of kernel image, little-endian
    le64sym _kernel_flags_le        // Informative flags, little-endian
    .quad   0               // reserved
    .quad   0               // reserved
    .quad   0               // reserved
    .ascii  ARM64_IMAGE_MAGIC       // Magic number
#ifdef CONFIG_EFI
    .long   pe_header - _head       // Offset to the PE header.
```

This is also the very first byte of an uncompressed kernel image.

Both of those cases jump to `stext` which starts the "real" action.

As mentioned in the comment, these two instructions are the first 64 bytes of a documented header described at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/v5.7/Documentation/arm64/booting.rst#4-call-the-kernel-image

**arm64 first MMU enabled instruction: `__primary_switched`**

I think it is [`__primary_switched` in head.S](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/v5.7/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S#L414):

```
/*
 * The following fragment of code is executed with the MMU enabled.
 *
 *   x0 = __PHYS_OFFSET
 */
__primary_switched:
```

At this point, the kernel appears to create page tables + maybe relocate itself such that the PC addresses match the symbols of the vmlinux ELF file. Therefore at this point you should be able to see meaningful function names in GDB without extra magic.

**arm64 secondary CPU entry point**

`secondary_holding_pen` defined at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/v5.7/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S#L691

Entry procedure further described at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux/blob/v5.7/arch/arm64/kernel/head.S#L691

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm voting up. and what does in a file /arch/um/kernel/um_arch.c function linux_main(int argc, char ** argv) than?

Comment: @zviad I have no idea! But since it is inside `arch/um`, I think that is that User Mode Linux thing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux which looks cool but I think is never use in regular operation.

Comment: from `#define __START_KERNEL_map  _AC(0xffffffff80000000, UL)` can we deduce that the load address for stock vmlinux is `0xffffffff80000000` ?

Comment: @AjB I'd need to think re/better understand things. Better just objdump + QEMU step debug it! :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com I believe you have a skeleton setup somewhere for just that right? Qemu/kvm + rootfs + linux Kernel

Comment: @AjB ⭐ https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat ⭐

Answer (score 4):

Several ways to look at it:

1. Device drivers are not programs. They are modules that are loaded into another program (the kernel). As such, they do not have a `main()` function.
2. The fact that all programs must have a `main()` function is only true for userspace applications. It does not apply to the kernel, nor to device drivers.

Comment: "...only true for userspace apps...", because they are mostly linked with libc which does initialization and then _calls_ main. The name main() is just a convention of libc.

Comment: Well, an application *could* choose to implement `_start` directly, or explicitly set an entry point with the linker. But that would remove the isolation of the C code against the platform dependent communication of command line args to the the application, force it to take care of running its constructor codes itself (which the compiler and linker helpfully emit), and force a explicit call to `exit()` before falling over the end of `_start`, as there is nothing `_start` can return to. Usually, the standard library takes care of all these gory details, and applications better make use of it.

Answer (score 3):

With `main()` you propably mean what `main()` is to a program, namely its "entry point".

For a module that is `init_module()`.

From [Linux Device Driver's 2nd Edition](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch02.html):

> Whereas an application performs a single task from beginning to end, a module registers itself in order to serve future requests, and its "main" function terminates immediately. In other words, the task of the function init_module (the module's entry point) is to prepare for later invocation of the module's functions; it's as though the module were saying, "Here I am, and this is what I can do." The second entry point of a module, cleanup_module, gets invoked just before the module is unloaded. It should tell the kernel, "I'm not there anymore; don't ask me to do anything else."

Comment: @alk, you should write a description in your own words.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Linux kernel has a main function, it is located in arch/x86/boot/main.c file. But Kernel execution starts from arch/x86/boot/header.S assembly file and the main() function is called from there by "calll main" instruction. 
Here is that main function:

```
void main(void)
{
    /* First, copy the boot header into the "zeropage" */
    copy_boot_params();

    /* Initialize the early-boot console */
    console_init();
    if (cmdline_find_option_bool("debug"))
        puts("early console in setup code.\n");

    /* End of heap check */
    init_heap();

    /* Make sure we have all the proper CPU support */
    if (validate_cpu()) {
        puts("Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate "
             "for your CPU.\n");
        die();
    }

    /* Tell the BIOS what CPU mode we intend to run in. */
    set_bios_mode();

    /* Detect memory layout */
    detect_memory();

    /* Set keyboard repeat rate (why?) and query the lock flags */
    keyboard_init();

    /* Query Intel SpeedStep (IST) information */
    query_ist();

    /* Query APM information */
#if defined(CONFIG_APM) || defined(CONFIG_APM_MODULE)
    query_apm_bios();
#endif

    /* Query EDD information */
#if defined(CONFIG_EDD) || defined(CONFIG_EDD_MODULE)
    query_edd();
#endif

    /* Set the video mode */
    set_video();

    /* Do the last things and invoke protected mode */
    go_to_protected_mode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the function name main() is just a common convention (there is no real reason to use it in kernel mode) the linux kernel does have a main() function for many architectures, and of course usermode linux has a main function.

Note the OS runtime loads the main() function to start an app, when an operating system boots there is no runtime, the kernel is simply loaded to a address by the boot loader which is loaded by the MBR which is loaded by the hardware. So while a kernel may contain a function called main it need not be the entry point.

See Also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Linux kernel source:

x86: linux-3.10-rc6/arch/x86/boot/main.c

arm64: linux-3.10-rc6/arch/arm64/kernel/asm-offsets.c