# Base address at which the linux kernel is loaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, elf, virtual-memory

I have a couple of doubts about how the kernel is loaded into memory. Upon inspecting `/proc/kallsyms` I'm able to find the address of various symbols in the kernel.

```
$ cat /proc/kallsyms | head -n 10
00000000 t __vectors_start
80008240 T asm_do_IRQ
80008240 T _stext
80008240 T __exception_text_start
80008244 T do_undefinstr
80008408 T do_IPI
8000840c T do_DataAbort
800084a8 T do_PrefetchAbort
80008544 t gic_handle_irq
800085a0 T secondary_startup
```

1. Is there any way I can find the base address at which the kernel is loaded?
2. In userspace, suppose I use a libc with say the `puts` function at an offset of 0x200. When loaded into memory at say the address `0x8048000`, I would be able to find the resolved `puts` at `0x8048000 + 0x200`. Would the same hold for the kernel? i.e. is the kernel image loaded up into memory as 1 contiguous `.text` section?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between physical addresses and virtual addresses?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Physical address eg: 80008240(actual RAM address). Virtual Address eg: 0x08048000, requires translation. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. The kernel is *loaded* at one physical location at boot, and *mapped* to another virtual location for every process on the system at runtime.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266063/does-kernel-have-main-function/33422401

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's not entirely correct - the kernel randomises the base physical address of the kernel (where it's decompressed) when it [can](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a8750ddca918032d6349adbf9a4b6555e7db20da/arch/x86/boot/compressed/kaslr.c#L667).

Answer (score 3):

for **MIPS** architecture

file *Platform* contain the field/variable "load-..." assigned with the location in physical address space.

example:

openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl-1.1.16/linux-brcm63xx_smp/linux-4.4.14/arch/mips/bcm63xx/Platform

```
#
# Broadcom BCM63XX boards
#
platform-$(CONFIG_BCM63XX)  += bcm63xx/
cflags-$(CONFIG_BCM63XX)    +=                  \
    -I$(srctree)/arch/mips/include/asm/mach-bcm63xx/
load-$(CONFIG_BCM63XX)      := 0xffffffff80010000
```

for **ARM** architecture

file *Makefile.boot* contain the field/variable "zreladdr-y" assigned with the location in physical address space.

example:

openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl-1.1.16/linux-brcm63xx_smp/linux-4.4.14/arch/arm/mach-omap1/Makefile.boot

```
   zreladdr-y       += 0x10008000
params_phys-y       := 0x10000100
initrd_phys-y       := 0x10800000
```

for **Microblaze** architecture

file *Makefile* contain the field/variable "UIMAGE_LOADADDR" assigned with the location in physical address space (exported from Xilinx ISE).

example:

openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_mips32_musl-1.1.16/linux-brcm63xx_smp/linux-4.4.14/arch/microblaze/boot/Makefile

```
UIMAGE_LOADADDR = $(CONFIG_KERNEL_BASE_ADDR)
```

Comment: I don't see how it helps the OP, he asks for a way to determind the kernel base address using a symbol (F) address he already has.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel is loaded at physical address of **1MiB** which is mapped on `PAGE_OFFSET + 0x00100000` (virtual address). usually `8MiB` of virtual space is reserved for kernel image starting from `PAGE_OFFSET + 0x00100000`

Answer (score 1):

As other answer states that Kernel base address is fixed for particular architecture. But due to many security issues kernel development community decided to make it random. It is called ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization).

By reading your question (or because I am reading it in 2017), you may be trying to find offset used in ASLR (or KASLR for kernel).

```
KASLR offset = address of symbol loaded in memory - address of symbol present in binary.
```

As your question states you already know address of symbol in memory from `/proc/kallsyms`.

We can find address of symbol in binary using `nm` utility and vmlinux file.

```
nm vmlinux | grep do_IPI
```

This will print address of symbol `do_IPI` in vmlinux file. Subtracting these two address will provide you KASLR offset.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using u-boot then at boot time bootloader usually print the kernel load address and entry point.

```
Erase Group Size: 512 Bytes
reading uImage
4670784 bytes read in 469 ms (9.5 MiB/s)
reading devicetree.dtb
20597 bytes read in 17 ms (1.2 MiB/s)
Booting Linux kernel with ramdisk and devicetree
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 02004000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.9.0-xilinx
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    4670720 Bytes = 4.5 MiB
   Load Address: 10000000
   Entry Point:  10000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 04000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x4000000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 1cb3d000, end 1cb45074 ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not always the case

Answer (score -2):

In the case of this ARM kernel the load address was at 0x80008000. Also, the kernel is loaded in a contiguous manner.

Comment: Meaning that we have 2GB user address space for ARM. Is that correct ?